# Multiple author but one mail

Tags: author, email

I'm new using Latex and I'm trying to put a mail in the end of my document, with a "*" by the side of the 1st author.
I've tried a lot of things but nothing gives what I want.

What I stay with for now is

```
\author{Author 1$^{1,2}$} \thanks{\href{mailto:author1@mail.com}{author1@mail.com}}\author{author2$^2$, author3$^2$}
```

Which gives me
[image]

And at the end of my document
[image]

But as you can see, there is an "and" between Author 1 and the others, that I don't want. How can I get rid of it ? Or have you another solution ?

Thank you everyone, hope I have been clear in my question.

EDIT :
I'm using a template I'm obligated to use.
From the template, if I want to add other author the "*" will get at the end of the line, but I want it just next to author 1. That is why I tried the solution above, but it gives me an "and" between the authors.

If it's not possible of course I will adapt, but maybe there is a solution to my problem ?

The code of the template is

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{url}
\fi


\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{Firstname Lastname$^1$}
\email{first.last@institution.com}
\affiliation{$^1$Laboratory, Department, University of City, Address, Country}
\begin{abstract}
\normalsize
Bablabla blablabla~\cite{Ref1}. Bliblibli blibli bli bliblibli~\cite{Ref2}.
Text.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{Ref1} A. First, B. Second, and C. Third, "On the Quantum Foundations", Quant. Inf. J. \textbf{1}, 1-10 (2023).

\bibitem{Ref2} A. Fourth, B. Fifth, and C. Sixth, "On the Quantum Revolutions", Quant. Inf. J. \textbf{1}, 11-20 (2023).

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, you should provide a Minimal Working Example, so we can reproduce your error. The behaviour of commands like `\author` relies heavily on the used `documentclass`. Without further information its nearly impossible to solve your problem. Also the manually typing of footnotes using math mode superscript should not be necessary in a good written LaTeX class.

Comment: Hi @lukeflo thank you for the comment, I will edit my question with more informations on my document. I'm not sure what you mean by "manually typing of footnotes using math mode superscript" ? I'm using a template I have to use for this paper, so there are some things I am obligated to put.

Comment: This can be answered after you've shown more of your code. But in general, LaTeX handles things like footnotes more sophisticated than manually typing them as superscript numbers. Maybe the reason is your template/documentclass. Thus, a MWE would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @lukeflo, I edited my post with the code I'm using :)

Comment: Maybe try to add every author with a separate `\author` command. Right now, you're setting the first author with single command and the last two *inside* of *one* command. Thus, the class interprets them as only two authors and adds an 'and' after the first name, as it is common for two authors.

Comment: I understand, it did work, thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @Wanon98, can you please add an answer yourself, so future readers can understand your solution at a glance, i.e. without guessing through the comments? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I have been told, using \author consider only one author so to put the "and" at the end of the list of author, you need to put each name in a separate \author

```
\author{Author 1$^{1,2}$} \thanks{\href{mailto:author1@mail.com}{author1@mail.com}}\author{author2$^2$}\author{author3$^2$}
```

Which gives
[image]